# Storm Spout not getting Ack

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have started using storm, so I create simple topology using [this tutorial](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial)

When I run my topology with `LocalCluster` and all seem fine,
My Problem is that I'm not getting ACK on the tuple, meaning my spout `ack` is never called.

my code is below - do you know why `ack` is not called ?

so my topology look like this

```java
public StormTopology build() {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout(HelloWorldSpout.class.getSimpleName(), 
             helloWorldSpout, spoutParallelism);

        HelloWorldBolt bolt = new  HelloWorldBolt();

        builder.setBolt(HelloWorldBolt.class.getSimpleName(), 
                   bolt, boltParallelism)
              .shuffleGrouping(HelloWorldSpout.class.getSimpleName());
}
```

My Spout look like this

```java
public class HelloWorldSpout  extends BaseRichSpout implements ISpout {
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("int"));
    }

    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
            SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    private static Boolean flag = false;
    public void nextTuple() {
        Utils.sleep(5000);

            //emit only 1 tuple - for testing
        if (!flag){
            this.collector.emit(new Values(6));
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void ack(Object msgId) {
        System.out.println("[HelloWorldSpout] ack on msgId" + msgId);
    }

    public void fail(Object msgId){
        System.out.println("[HelloWorldSpout] fail on msgId" + msgId);
    }
}
```

and my bolt look like this

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloWorldBolt extends BaseRichBolt{
    private OutputCollector collector;

    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, 
                    OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
        logger.info("preparing HelloWorldBolt");
    }

    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        System.out.println("[HelloWorldBolt] got" + tuple.getInteger(0));
        this.collector.ack(tuple);
    }

    public void cleanup() {
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I really like your pattern of "HelloWorldSpout.class.getSimpleName()" in the shuffle grouping. I dont understand why so many java apis depend on magic strings and magic numbers (as opposed to enums), but your pattern is a nice way to not get burned.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your emit() method in the spout has only one argument, so that tuple isn't anchored.  That's why you're not getting a call back to the ack() method in the spout even though you're ack'ing the tuple in the bolt.

To get this to work, you need to modify your spout to emit a second argument which is the message id.  It is this id that's passed back to the ack() method in the spout:

```
public void nextTuple() {
    Utils.sleep(5000);

        //emit only 1 tuple - for testing
    if (!flag){
        Object msgId = "ID 6";  // this can be any object
        this.collector.emit(new Values(6), msgId);
        flag = true;
    }
}


@Override
public void ack(Object msgId) {
    //  msgId should be "ID 6"
    System.out.println("[HelloWorldSpout] ack on msgId" + msgId);
}
```