# Not receiving ack in this storm topology?

Tags: apache-storm

I am new with storm, and I am running a toplogy

```
public class FakeCallLogReaderSpout implements IRichSpout {
   //Create instance for SpoutOutputCollector which passes tuples to bolt.
   private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
   private boolean completed = false;

   //Create instance for TopologyContext which contains topology data.
   private TopologyContext context;

   //Create instance for Random class.
   private Random randomGenerator = new Random();
   private Integer idx = 0;

   @Override
   public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
      this.context = context;
      this.collector = collector;
   }

   @Override
   public void nextTuple() {
      if(this.idx <= 1000) {
         List<String> mobileNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
         mobileNumbers.add("1234123401");
         mobileNumbers.add("1234123402");
         mobileNumbers.add("1234123403");
         mobileNumbers.add("1234123404");

         Integer localIdx = 0;
         while(localIdx++ < 100 && this.idx++ < 1000) {
            String fromMobileNumber = mobileNumbers.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(4));
            String toMobileNumber = mobileNumbers.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(4));

            while(fromMobileNumber == toMobileNumber) {
               toMobileNumber = mobileNumbers.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(4));
            }

            Integer duration = randomGenerator.nextInt(60);
            this.collector.emit(new Values(fromMobileNumber, toMobileNumber, duration),duration);
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("from", "to", "duration"));
   }

   //Override all the interface methods
   @Override
   public void close() {}

   public boolean isDistributed() {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void activate() {}

   @Override 
   public void deactivate() {}

   @Override
   public void ack(Object msgId) {
       System.out.println(msgId);
   }

   @Override
   public void fail(Object msgId) {}

   @Override
   public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      return null;
   }
}
```

---

```
//Create a class CallLogCreatorBolt which implement IRichBolt interface
public class CallLogCreatorBolt implements IRichBolt {
   //Create instance for OutputCollector which collects and emits tuples to produce output
   private OutputCollector collector;

   @Override
   public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
      this.collector = collector;
   }

   @Override
   public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
      String from = tuple.getString(0);
      String to = tuple.getString(1);
      Integer duration = tuple.getInteger(2);
      collector.emit(new Values(from + " - " + to, duration));
   }

   @Override
   public void cleanup() {}

   @Override
   public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("call", "duration"));
   }

   @Override
   public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      return null;
   }
```

### }

```
public class CallLogCounterBolt implements IRichBolt {
   Map<String, Integer> counterMap;
   private OutputCollector collector;

   @Override
   public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
      this.counterMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      this.collector = collector;
   }

   @Override
   public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
      String call = tuple.getString(0);
      Integer duration = tuple.getInteger(1);

      if(!counterMap.containsKey(call)){
         counterMap.put(call, 1);
      }else{
         Integer c = counterMap.get(call) + 1;
         counterMap.put(call, c);
      }

      collector.ack(tuple);
   }

   @Override
   public void cleanup() {
      for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:counterMap.entrySet()){
         System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : " + entry.getValue());
      }
   }

   @Override    
   public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("call"));
   }

   @Override
   public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      return null;
   }

}
```

I am calling `collector.ack(tuple)` from CallLogCounterBolt, the but ack is not getting called.

Does anybody have any idea why it is not getting called?

Also if drop the ack altogether from the code, what impact will it have?

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260291/storm-spout-not-getting-ack

Answer (score 0):

You need to anchor and ack tuple in each bolt. I guess your topology is like `FakeCallLogReaderSpout` => `CallLogCreatorBolt`=> `CallLogCounterBolt`. Thus, in `CallLogCreatorBolt` you should do

```
collector.emit(tuple, new Values(from + " - " + to, duration));
collector.ack();
```

Read https://storm.apache.org/releases/0.10.0/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html for more details.